# python running test: ImproperlyConfigured

Tags: django, unit-testing, python-2.7

I'm trying to run some testes for django (1.7) project.

have created a `test_models.py`  directory `/tests/` under project directory.

On running test

```
>> python tests/test_models.py -v
```

Error:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting CACHES, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

Although
following django stanards commands works fine

```
>> python manage.py runserver
>> python manage.py shell
```

**test_models.py**

```
import unittest
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from accounts.models import school

class TestAccounts(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        admin_user = User.objects.get_or_create(
            username="testuser", password=111)
        self.admin = admin_user[0]

        self.school_name = "merucabs"
        self.email = "info@merucabs.com"

    def test_school(self):
        print "Testing school ..."
        school = School(name=self.school_name)
        school.created_by = self.admin
        school.updated_by = self.admin
        school.save()
        self.school = school
        self.assertEqual(self.school.name, self.school_name)



def suite():
    suite = unittest.TestSuite()
    suite.addTests(unittest.makeSuite(TestAccounts))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: already tried solutions suggested here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24011428/django-core-exceptions-improperlyconfigured-requested-setting-caches-but-setti ?

Comment: @aberna: tried but no help

Comment: @Alasdair code for test_models.py

Comment: Do you have full traceback?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can [run Django tests](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/testing/overview/#running-tests) with the `test` command.

```
./manage.py test tests/test_models
```

If you want to run your tests as a stand alone script (i.e. python `tests/test_models.py`), then you have to set the `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` environment variable. As of Django 1.7, you must call `django.setup()` as well.

```
import django
import os
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'mysite.settings'
django.setup()
```