# How to write a stand-alone Python script working with Django modules?

Tags: django

In PyCharm, I created a blank new Django app. Having created some models and issued `manage.py makemigrations` and `manage.py migrate`, I tried to write a standalone script that would populate the database with initial data. In its imports I wrote:

```
from MyApp.models import Model1, Model2, …
```

Sadly, running this script in PyCharm throws an exception: `django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting DEFAULT_TABLESPACE, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.`

I Googled this exception, and found an answer in SO https://stackoverflow.com/a/27455703/4385532 advising to put this in the top of my script:

```
import os

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'mysite.settings'
```

So I did. Sadly, this didn’t fix the issue. Now I am greeted with another exception:
`django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet.`

What should I do?

Comment: Did you also do this: `import django; django.setup()`?

Comment: Did you configure PyCharm project to be a Django one? There's a couple settings there that you need to set up.

Comment: Unless you are doing something very unusual, 'a script to populate the database with initial data' would be a perfect use case for either fixtures or a data migration, depending on whether the data can be loaded as is (ie from json) or requires some manipulation. Check out those options before you attempt anything more complicated.

Comment: @bernie, Thanks! adding this line seems to have fixed the issue.

Comment: @ChidG Well I was importing data from `xls` files. The script took f#cking 10 hours to complete, while importing the same data from `xls` files to Python dicts takes seconds. The resulting `.sqlite3` file is `14.3 MB` large, for sake why does writing `14.3 MB` data to HDD take 10 hours? Thanks for pointing fixtures  and data migrations to me, I'll definitely take a look at this if I ever have to re-import this data, perhaps – just perhaps – it will be faster.

Comment: You could use a data migration in that case. The performance issue may be something different and not something I can comment on without knowing a lot more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you also do:

```
import django 
django.setup()
```

To load your models.

Documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/settings/#calling-django-setup-is-required-for-standalone-django-usage